# Java pass input to a function from terminal

Tags: java, command-line

Is there any way I can write a command in the terminal like

> > config.group1.val1

and somehow parse this command and send "group1" and "val1" as two parameters in a Java function?

I can't send it in main function through args[] array.

Comment: why not? just split the input string and pass individual tokens in your method as parameters

Comment: How can read the command written in terminal and parse it to pass to java code. any idea?

Comment: why don't you use a scanner instead, since you can't get them from args[]?

Comment: program flow: I have a config file that contains [groups] key1 = value1 like this. it has multiple groups and arbitrary number of key value pairs. I have write a Ruby/Java code that will parse the config file calling the function at boot time and when the user writes a command in the terminal like >>config.group1.key1 it should return "value1".

Comment: I have already parsed the file creating a HashMap<String1, Hashmap<String2, String3>> where String1 is the group name, String2 is the key name and String3 is the value. Now to use map.get I need to fetch the String1 & String2 from the terminal coz user will only fire the before mentioned command and I have get them to find the result in the hashmap. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

It can be done as next:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
// get the next line from the terminal
String line = scanner.nextLine();
// split it using . as separator
String[] params = line.split("\\.");
// Default value
String value = "unknown";
// Assuming that the name of your map is "map"
Map<String, String> subMap = map.get(params[1]);
if (subMap != null && subMap.containsKey(params[2])) {
    value = subMap.get(params[2]);
}
// print the value found
System.out.println(value);
```

Comment: It's getting a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 exception at first line

Comment: this code assumes that you launch your program with config.group1.val1 as paramter

Comment: I mean java MyClass config.group1.val1

Comment: Can you please read the comments above in the post. then that will make you understand easily. probably my question is not clear enough